# importing csv file into SQL using Logic apps 2020

Tags: sql, csv, import, azure-logic-apps

I have seen several older posts talking about how to import a csv file into SQL using Logic Apps however i have not seen anything thats easy to implement and doesn't require 85+ steps to do.

Has anyone come up with an easy way? I've done this million times using SQL SSIS or other tools to automate but nothing in Logic Apps?

Please let me know if you have a simple solution.

Comment: Does [this](https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/) solution meet your requirement ?

Comment: May I know how many csv do you want to import to sql ? In other words, you want to import csv to sql just a few times or want to use the logic import csv to sql many times(consistently) ? If just import csv a few times, I can provide a workaround for your reference. If want many times, you may need to pay extra cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no out-of box connector or function in LogicApp which parses a CSV file .

You can always vote for new features feedback: [Read a csv file and bulk load into Azure SQL table](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/18420946-read-a-csv-file-and-bulk-load-into-azure-sql-table)

[image]

Logic App Teams suggest us look at Azure Data Factory to assist with this.

For example: [Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL Database by using the Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) and the blog https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/ @Hury Shen provided in comment.

We can't import the csv file to into SQL directly, that's these posts look very complex and involve many steps. Just for Logic Apps, there isn't such an easy way for now.